# Creating a loop that calculates the rolling mean of a vector for different rolling mean lengths

Tags: r, for-loop, rolling-computation

I am trying to create a "for loop" setup that is going calculate different rolling means of a return series, where I use rolling means ranging from the last 2 observations to the last 16 observations. kϵ[2,16]. I've been trying to use a function like this, where the "rollmean" is a function from zoo. This produces the warning "Warning message:
In roll[i] <- rollmean(x, i) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"
Can someone please help me?

```
rollk <- function(x, kfrom= 2, kto=16){
roll <- as.list(kto-kfrom+1)
for (i in kfrom:kto){
roll[i]<- rollmean(x, i)
return(roll)
}}
```

Comment: Try `roll[[i]]` -- you've confused a vector element w/ a list element.  Ahhhh rats, ninja'd by Sven   :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want

```
# library(zoo)
rollk <- function(x, kfrom = 2, kto = 16){
  roll <- list()
  ft <- kfrom:kto
  for (i in seq_along(ft)){
    roll[[i]]<- rollmean(x, ft[i])   
  }
  return(roll)
}
```

There are several problems in your function:

- You need `[[` to access a single list element, not `[`.
- You want a list of length `length(krom:kto)`. Now, `i` starts at `1`, not at `kfrom`.
- Now, `roll` is returned *after* the `for` loop. Hence, the function returns a single list containing *all* values.

---

A shorter equivalent of the function above:

```
rollk2 <- function(x, kfrom = 2, kto = 16)
  lapply(seq(kfrom, kto), function(i) na.omit(filter(x, 1 / rep(i, i))))
```

It does not require loading additional packages.

Comment: Thanks alot, that did the trick! As you might have understood I'm quite new to R and the help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)
lapply(2:16, rollmean, x = x)
```